# How to push my branch to existing Github repo without merging it to master?

Tags: git, github

I'm new to Git and have pulled down a repo, created a new branch and made some changes to a file.

Now I want to push my changes back up to Github so I can create a pull request, but I don't want to merge my changes with master.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you already committed the changes?

Comment: Use `git push origin your_new_branch`.  After that, you may setup a pull request involving that branch if you want to.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks, want to make that an answer?

Comment: @MeltingDog The thing is, there are already several canonical answers out there, and there is not much I can here which would add to that.